# Python code to run cmd as admin and execute a command

Tags: python, windows, cmd, parameters, runas

I want to run a specific cmd code which can be executed only if the cmd is run with administrator privileges.

this is my code:

```
import ctypes, sys

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    print "Admin success"
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u'runas',unicode('cmd.exe'),"REG ADD 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Exclusions\Paths' /v 'C:\MyFolderwithNoSpaces' /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f/c ", None, 1)
```

The runas command will popup an UAC. I want this `REG ADD 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Exclusions\Paths' /v 'C:\MyFolderwithNoSpaces' /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f/c` to run with admin rights in Windows. Please help me correct the code or suggest a better syntax.

Comment: It's supposed to ask for consent on the secure desktop. It's working as designed. There are ways around the UAC consent dialog, but doing so requires administrator access the first time in order to create a task or install a service.

Comment: For `ShellExecuteW` you should be using all `unicode` string literals. Unfortunately raw `unicode` literals are broken in Python 2 (`\u` and `\U` escapes are still evaluated). You can use forward slash and normalize, e.g. `u"REG ADD '%s' /v '%s' /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f/c" % (os.path.normpath(u"HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Microsoft Antimalware/Exclusions/Paths"), os.path.normpath(u"C:/MyFolderwithNoSpaces"))`.

Comment: @eryksun I ran your command and a white window just popped up and closed too fast Couldn't see what was there. But then I checked the hklm registry, the entry I tried to add wasn't there.